# Does crimson spread in the mobile edition?

Tags: terraria-mobile

Everyone is saying that crimson spreads but that doesn't seem to be happening on the mobile edition. Can you please tell my why? I keep coming back every day in and I know that it only spreads on dirt - but its not spreading!

Answer (score 1):

**No known bug causing Crimson not to spread is recorded for any platform.**

In Normal Mode, Crimson spreads through grass across dirt blocks, requiring direct contact from other Crimson grass or a thorny bush. This includes growing new Crimson grass or converting existing grass into Crimson. Before Hardmode, Crimstone and other forms of Crimson do not contribute to its spread, and cannot convert nearby grass. The spread of Crimson can be stopped by Sunflowers, just like Corruption. Also, Crimson will only spread while the world is active; it won't spread while the game is closed, a different world is open, or while the game is paused.

Source: http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Crimson

Answer (score -3):

I believe the crimson spreads after you go into hard mode, and does not spread before that.

Comment: This is not the way the game is designed, nor is there any known bug to this effect for the Mobile version. Considering that, why do you believe what you claim?